# What is the use of "and N" in this code?

Tags: c++, while-loop, logical-operators

C++ Code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int N;
    cin>>N;
    int *A = new int[N];
    int i=0;
    for(i=0;i<N;i++)
        cin>>A[i];
    while(cout<<A[--N]<<' ' and N);
    delete[] A;
    return 0;
}
```

Print the integers of the array in the reverse order in a single line separated by a space.
Does anyone know what is "and N" do in cout statement?

Answer (score 2):

It's a cryptic way of writing:

```
while( (cout<<A[--N]<<' ') and (N != 0) );
//    output is successful and N is not equal to zero.
```

It could be written more clearly as:

```
for ( ; N != 0; --N)
{
    cout << A[N-1] << ' ';
}
```

Since it's theoretically possible for `N` to be negative, it will be better to use:

```
for ( ; N > 0; --N)
{
    cout << A[N-1] << ' ';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`N` is an integer variable, value of type `int` can be implicitly converted to `bool` (non zero becomes `true` and zero becomes `false`). So the expression basically sais execute when result of `operator<<` converted to `bool` is true **and** `N` is not equal to zero. Logically this code

```
while(cout<<A[--N]<<' ' and N);
```

is equal to:

```
do {
   bool b1 = cout<<A[--N]<<' ';
   bool b2 = N;
} while( b1 and b2 );
```

actual code is a little different due to short circuit but that differences are unimportant in this case.

Answer (score 1):

The part `and N` that can be also written like `&& N` of the while statement

```
while(cout<<A[--N]<<' ' and N);
```

that as it has been pointed out can be rewritten like

```
while(cout<<A[--N]<<' ' && N != 0);
```

checks that `N` that is being decreased (`A[--N]`) in each iteration of the loop is not equal to 0.

So the loop outputs elements okf the array in the reverse order.

The word `and` is a so-called alternative token for the primary token `&&`.

Answer (score 0):

It is just a way of writing the code by some programmers. 
It is actually written as

```
while( (cout<<A[--N]<<' ')  and (N != 0) );
```

Basically 'and' operator returns true when both operands are non zero values.
So cout will give number of characters it printed which will be non zero in this case and until the value of N becomes zero your loop will be execute.